# Bluetooth paired but not connected ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have seen carefully many suggestions online, yet not able to overcome the issue. I was able to connect yesterday and use my bluetooth speaker but not today.

from bluetoothctl

```
~$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 0C:D2:92:78:36:FA billy-Lenovo-G500s [default]
[NEW] Device FC:A8:9A:A6:8F:B2 JBL Flip 3
[bluetooth]# devices
Device FC:A8:9A:A6:8F:B2 JBL Flip 3
[bluetooth]# connect FC:A8:9A:A6:8F:B2 
Attempting to connect to FC:A8:9A:A6:8F:B2
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]#
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with gnome and my bluez Version: 5.37-0ubuntu5
some good idea?

/B

Answer (score 16):

I did what Bradyn Claycomb suggested but it was not enough so I improved it as follows:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth 
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Then I can connect to my Bluetooth headphone from Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: After upgrade from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 I had this issue. This solution fixed my issue. I also had poor output quality that another thread came with solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/676853/bluetooth-headset-with-poor-sound-quality-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with my Jaybird X2 earbuds and this is what solved it for me:

Run

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install ofono
```

Followed by a reboot.

If I understand correctly, there is a known bug with bluetooth in 16.04 and this worked in my case. Let us know if this works.

Comment: You have to open and restart bluetooth and then sometimes it works. But then it doesn t play the bass always. Bizarre, appreciated though. /B

Comment: Aren't there built in EQ settings for devices? Is it possible that Ubuntu is "muting" the bass in this case? Or is it strictly signal related?

Comment: `pacmd set-card-profile <index> a2dp_sink`
fixed the bass problem for me. Get index with `pacmd list`.

Comment: This worked for me after also adding

`pulseaudio -k;
pulseaudio --start`

as described in answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1024034/811174

Before adding this it was wavering between Connected: yes and Connected: no

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Bluetooth redirection of sound to the audio device (Score K1-MINI) is reliable only if sound from Rythmbox music player software is already going to the laptop (Dell Vostro 3550) speakers BEFORE making the Bluetooth connection to the Bluetooth speakers. Then it takes a few seconds to change over in mid stream. Some how, (without an audio stream), the Bluetooth connection just seems to stay connected to the old output destination, even when you use the “Test Sound” button in sound settings.