# Why doesn't my android devices (Phones, Tabs) transfer files to my Ubuntu machine over bluetooth?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, android

I have been using Ubuntu for some time now, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. While my file transfers happens seamlessly on windows via bluetooth, I am yet to make a single successful file transfer on Ubuntu. Please help. I use Ubuntu 16.04

Edit - I switch on my laptop's bluetooth. Next I try to send a file from my phone or tab to my laptop. My laptop's bluetooth name comes as *ubuntu-0*. But when I try to send a file through to my laptop from the remote device the transaction invariably fails.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/831732/bluetooth-paired-but-not-connected-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Comment: @JuanAntonio Mostly lollipop and marshmallow

Comment: @ElderGeek ... the link shared by you is just for bluetooth speakers. I am also concerned about bluetooth file transfers from and to a mobile device.

Comment: My apologies for any confusion. I was under the impression that the root cause of your problem was a failure to pair (based on the title and limited content of your question and the post I linked looked useful. If you have further details that you could [edit] into your post in order to help us help you, that would be most welcome! How are you attempting to pair your devices?

Comment: @ElderGeek I have edited my question to include further details. :)