# bluetooth on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 20.04, firmware

I have ubuntu 20 lst installed and bluetooth only works from the laptop to the mobile.
when trying to send a file from the mobile, it says sending error.

sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

```
[    1.909755] usb 2-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   12.586903] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.586927] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.586932] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.586935] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.586939] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.465175] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   13.466153] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   13.466155] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   15.118623] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   15.118652] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   15.118661] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[   15.552168] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
[   29.454321] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.454322] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.454326] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   83.635119] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   83.635126] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   83.635135] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  406.108645] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 3
[  406.108654] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 3
[  406.108657] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below commands taken from [Bluetooth paired but not connected ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831732/bluetooth-paired-but-not-connected-ubuntu-16-04).

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo apt-get install ofono
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth 
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: Ok, @Shehan.
bluetooth on ubuntu 20.04 LTS, it already works.
:)