# audio.conf missing

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, a2dp

Xubuntu 16.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux private-client 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When connecting my new August EP650 bluetooth-headset, it pairs but I don't hear anything

With Pulse-Audio's configurations open you can watch a new item showing up immediately after pairing. On the left it is labelled "EP650" and there is a drop-down box named "HiFi-Stereo-A2DP-snk-profile" (I translated it from German)

but

```
$ sdptool search --bdaddr local a2snk
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory
```

and

```
$ sdptool search --bdaddr local a2src
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory
```

After reading some threads, I realized, that there is no: `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`

I am able to do some Linux-stuff you tell me, but I do not know what is wrong and do not know, how to get that file?

Does it come with any application?

Thanks for any helpful advise.

Answer (score 16):

The audio.conf file is not needed.  There is a bug in either Bluez or Pulseaudio causing issues if you want to use A2DP

A current work around is to

```
wget https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae/archive/d698974910bbb7d016ec0ad08c1bf41b4b524364.zip
mv ~/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae-d698974910bbb7d016ec0ad08c1bf41b4b524364/a2dp.py .a2dp.py
```

Then after connecting to the headset run `./a2dp.py` in terminal and enter the number for your headset and let the python script do the rest

Comment: $ sudo ./a2dp.py
Connection MADE
Selecting device:
Device MAC: 00:12:D0:02:F7:EB
Command: pacmd list-sinks failed with status: 1
stderr: Home directory not accessible: Keine Berechtigung - Translation: No authorization/permission
Es läuft kein PulseAudio-Dienst oder nicht als Sessiondienst. - Translation: There is no Pulse-Audio-Service running, at least not as a Session-service.

Exiting bluetoothctl

Comment: Have you installed updates since installing as there was an issue with connecting to headsets crashing pulseaudio that was fixed `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @longman There is no reason to use sudo for this command

Comment: This works flawlessly. Don't forget to change the permissions to allow the file to be executed as program.

Comment: any ideas on how to make the changes this script makes permanent?

Comment: confirming this works on 17.10 with sony WH1000mx2 how does this still not work out of the box..

Comment: this was working for quite a while... but it stopped working after the last upgrades I've made...

Comment: Confirmed this works on Pop!_OS 18.10 on ThinkPad X1 Extreme on WH-1000XM3! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Simply apply your required changes on `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` instead of
`/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` as this file has been removed in new versions.

and for solve `Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00`
see below link and make some changes on `dbus-org.bluez.service` to use
features of `blueZ-4` as `sdptool` in `blueZ-5` not work properly.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 5):

Get the index of your card:

```
pacmd list-cards
```

Set the cards profile to a2dp (example: index 2):

```
pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink
```

Credit to `develmusa` of the ArchLinux forums:  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1720877#p1720877