# Bluetooth headphones in High Fidelity Playback not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of **bluetooth headphones** (Andoer LH-811). Connecting them to my **Ubuntu 16.04** they work only in *Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)* mode. If I go on sound settings and try to switch to *High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)* it automatically brings me back to the laptop's speakers.

Note that on the same laptop but with *Ubuntu 16.10* I don't have this problem.

How to make them work?

Comment: Maybe by using higher version of your bluetooth manager and/or pulseaudio from a PPA?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/864841/300665)  It is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1577197)