# Wireless Earphones Poor sound Quality in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth

I'm using Dell latitude 5480 with dual boot, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My [Sony C200 wireless earphones](https://www.sony.com/electronics/in-ear-headphones/wi-c200) works pretty decent with Windows 10, but on Ubuntu I've searched through all topics which were:

1. changing HSP/HFP to A2DP.
2. adding following text to sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

> Automatically connect both A2DP and HFP/HSP profiles for incoming
>   connections. Some headsets that support both profiles will only connect the
>   other one automatically so the default setting of true is usually a good
>   idea.

AutoConnect=true 
and setting:
MultiProfile = multiple

[Bluetooth headset with poor sound quality on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676853/bluetooth-headset-with-poor-sound-quality-on-ubuntu)

none of  were working for better and decent sound quality. if it is possible anyone help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service

Change

ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

to

ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: This worked for me on Xubuntu 22.04. No new packages needed to be loaded, but a reboot did appear necessary: system locked up hard when pavucontrol tried to access the pulseaudio daemon.

Comment: Also, when you do this, make sure to select A2DP in pavucontrol, as that is the default used. In my case at least, it doesn't default to A2DP... probably a setting I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the bit depth of the equipment:
`sudo lshw -C sound`

Try it here...
`gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

```
##; resample-method = speex-float-1
; resample-method = src-sinc-best-quality

; flat-volumes = yes

##; default-sample-format = s16le
##; default-sample-format = s32le
##; default-sample-format = s64le
##; default-sample-format = float16le
##; default-sample-format = float32le
; default-sample-format = float64le
##; default-sample-rate = 44100
##; default-sample-rate = 48000
; default-sample-rate = 88200
##; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
; alternate-sample-rate = 96000
; default-sample-channels = 2
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
```

I have a better sound than in Windows, everywhere, on Bluetooth speakers and headphones.

Comment: Edit it yourself, I deleted my account.