# Sound output configuration option missing in settings on 22.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.04

When connecting an audio device over bluetooth the audio quality is very poor and it gets interrupted a lot. It seems that I have the same problem as [this asker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676853/bluetooth-headset-with-poor-sound-quality-on-ubuntu).

The solution would be easy, but I'm [missing the 'Configuration' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJwnJ.png) as it appears in other answers referring to older versions.

Where did the option move in 22.04? What am I missing?

Comment: The image in your link doesn't show a Bluetooth device. Some, perhaps most, Bluetooth audio device with a microphone can operate in two modes: HFP (mono + mic) or A2DP (HiFi Stereo, no mic) and this modes can indeed be selected from a dropdown menu.

Comment: But the sound is coming from my speaker (JBL Go 3) when I select this one, so it must be it. Also, the same computer and same speaker have no problems on Windows 11.